# Traceroute for MAC address

Tags: linux, macos, routes, command

I'm having a problem in my network and I need to know with path the source and destination MAC address of the test environment are taking.

GNU/Linux has any command like this, similar to `mtr` or `traceroute` to MAC address?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot ping or traceroute a MAC on another network segment.

MAC addresses are used on your local network, when you can just broadcast a message to all network devices. If routers comes into place you need some kind of hierarchy or routing information. So when sending from one network to another you need a protocol like for example IP.